# Error when using (keras) and (tensorflow) for ANN

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I used this code from

```
modelann <- keras_model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predictions)
modelann %>% compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = "mse", metrics = list("mean_absolute_error"))
modelann %>% fit(train_data, epochs = 100, batch_size = 100)`
```

I get this error when I run the last line

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 2021-05-04
> 10:17:46.597524: I
> tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of
> the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2) Error in
> py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: in user
> code:
> C:\Users\LENOVO1\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805
> train_function * return step_function(self, iterator)'
> C:\Users\LENOVO1\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795
> step_function  **  outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step,
> args=(data,))
> C:\Users\LENOVO1\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259
> run         return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args,
> kwargs=kwargs)
> C:\Users\LENOVO1\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730
> call_for_each_replica         return self._call_for_each_replica(fn,
> args, kwargs)
> C:\Users\LENOVO1\ANACON~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417
> _call_for_each_replica         return fn(*args, **kwargs)     C:\Users\LENOVO1\AN`

Comment: When specifying the error you have to include the whole error stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: The error traceback is long, I will divide it into two parts.

Comment: You can add this in the description

Comment: Guys,any response?